# How to connect 2 tables using LINQ ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

**Images table structure:**

```
Id
AccountId
Url
```

**Slides table structure:**

```
Id
AccountId
ImageId
```

I have two requests:

```
ViewBag.userId = user.Id;
ViewBag.images = context.Images.Where(c => c.AccountId == user.Id).Select(c => c);
ViewBag.slides = context.Slides.Where(c => c.AccountId == user.Id).Select(c => c);
```

***Question***: 
How can I change the code `ViewBag.slides =` to get the result `slides.ImageId = images.Id`. I'm trying to get the url of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a LINQ join

```
var slidesForUser= ( from a in context.Images
                       join b in  context.Slides on a.Id equals b.ImageId 
                      where a.AccountId == user.Id select b).ToList();
```

`slidesForUser` variable will be a list of `Slides` (for those recors which matches the join and where condition). If you prefer to select only one property (Ex :ImageUrl), simply update the select part to be `select b.ImageUrl`

Answer (score 0):

> I hope get url picture.

If you just want the URL of the picture starting from slides you can use SelectMany

```
ViewBag.slides = context.Slides
    .Where(c => c.AccountId == user.Id)
    .SelectMany(c => c.Images)
    .Select(i => i.Url);
```